# Is it possible to have a "real" \belowdisplayshortskip?

Tags: equations, spacing

I think this is a tough one. Have you ever wondered why TeX sometimes produces vertical spacing around equations that is far from satisfactory? An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\textheight}{2.93cm}
\begin{document}
A short line,
\[ a = b_{11}^2 b_{12}^2 b_{13}^2 b_{14}^2, \]
a long line containing superscripts $\delta^{22}\beta^{22}$,
almost touching the above formula,
\[ c = d, \]
and another short line,
\[ e = f. \]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

In my opinion, the vertical space after the first display is much too small, whereas after the second one it's too large.

Before I ask the question, I'd like to explain this behaviour: The first text line is short and doesn't overlap the diplay that follows, so TeX put only little vertical space in between, namely `\abovedisplayshortskip`. This is good. Now there is also `\belowdisplayshortskip`, but this doesn't behave as you might expect: It does control the vertical space *after* the display, but the space becomes small if the line *above* the display is short (which I find weird). This also explains why the space after the second display is large.

Now my question: Is there any way to obtain a `\belowdisplayshortskip` that becomes short if there is no overlap *after* the display? My fear is that in TeX/LaTeX the answer is no, but maybe with XeTeX or LuaTeX one can do something?

(I do have a fix for the problem, but this fix is also far from satisfactory. I set `\belowdisplayshortskip=9pt plus 3pt minus 5pt`, and then after each display where there is no overlap with the next line, I put a macro that makes the vertical space shorter. This is a real nuisance if one makes changes in the text.)

Comment: I'd say that the behavior (like all behaviors of TeX) is intentional. You can modify it only in LuaTeX where you can edit the internal lists and hook into TeX's processing.

Comment: OK, I think Knuth himself said that every remaining bug in TeX is a feature. I still consider this one a bug since I strongly dislike the spacing in the output.

Comment: @Hendrik: He said that will only be the case after he dies. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX):  ""absolutely final change (to be made after my death)" will be to change the version number to π, at which point all remaining bugs will become features"

Comment: A change to fix this is unlikely to be made in TeX since that would change document layout and one of TeX's goals is to be stable.

Comment: I should add that this behavior is explicitly described in The TeXbook, so it seems like it was a design decision, rather than a bug. "If the predisplaysize is short enough so that it doesn’t overlap the displayed formula, the glue above and below the display will be “short” by comparison with the glue that is used when there is an overlap."

Comment: @TH1: Of course TeX has to be stable. But one could (I think should!) still offer it as an option in some package.

Comment: @TH2: I know that this is described in the TeXbook; this is where I understood what happens. But it is not explained there _why_ it is done like this. I always thought it was a compromise since computers were _a lot_ slower when TeX was written.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: You're probably right about that. It seems like an odd design decision. I'm certainly not qualified to answer why Knuth designed it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding better ways to handle displayed math including (sub)formulanumbers is on the todo list for luatex, but in the current situation even in luatex doing this is far from trivial.

The issue is that the engine puts the display on the page as a full-width line, and it takes considerable effort to extract the actual width(s) from that, even with luatex node processing.

Comment: I'm curious why that would be. I don't know anything about LuaTeX's node processing, but a display looks like an `\hbox(0.0+0.0)x<width>` followed by `\penalty 10000`, followed by `\glue(\abovedisplayskip)` followed by `\glue(\baselineskip)`, followed by the `\hbox` containing the display, shifted some amount, followed by `\penalty 0`, followed by `\glue(\belowdisplayskip)`. If you can pull apart boxes on the MVL, it should be doable. It's probably doable in Knuth's TeX if you stick the display in a `\vbox` (which is how I got that information) and using things like `\lastbox` and `\lastskip`.

Comment: @TH: One problem I see is that the next piece of paragraph needs to get typeset in order to see if there is overlap.

Comment: ... as Hendrik says. Note that the paragraph itself is not a big issue, but the potential page break that it can introduce is disastrous.

Comment: I'm missing something here, if the line above the display is short, it is very logical to decrease the above skip, but why TeX is changing the below skip too? I don't see the point.

Comment: Well, that is the point: nobody sees the point (except DEK, obviously)

Comment: @Khaled: But you got the point I'm aiming at! I also don't understand why one should want to change the skip below in this way.

Comment: @Taco: I fear that there will be no really satisfactory answer coming. Your answer, though negative, contains at least a little spark of hope, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

An edit pushed up this question to the front page, so here's my take:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A short line,
\[ a = b_{11}^2 b_{12}^2 b_{13}^2 b_{14}^2, \]
a long line containing superscripts $\delta^{22}\beta^{22}$,
almost touching the above formula,
\[ c = d, \]
and another short line,
\[ e = f \]
followed by a longer line that we want to go beyond the limit so it wraps.

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\belowdisplayshortskip=\belowdisplayskip

A short line,
\[ a = b_{11}^2 b_{12}^2 b_{13}^2 b_{14}^2, \]
a long line containing superscripts $\delta^{22}\beta^{22}$,
almost touching the above formula,
\[ c = d, \]
and another short line,
\[ e = f \]
followed by a longer line that we want to go beyond the limit so it wraps.
\end{document}
```

[image]

TeX uses `\belowdisplayshortskip` if it used `\abovedisplayshortskip` before the display, but the parameters are independent: there's no law that imposes

```
\belowdisplayshortskip=\abovedisplayshortskip
```

and the parameter can be set to whatsoever value one wants. Setting it equal to `\belowdisplayskip` seems quite drastic, though.

Doing automatic adjustments might be really difficult; one can think of changing the parameter locally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A short line,
\begingroup\belowdisplayshortskip=\belowdisplayskip
\[
  a = b_{11}^2 b_{12}^2 b_{13}^2 b_{14}^2,
\]\endgroup
a long line containing superscripts $\delta^{22}\beta^{22}$,
almost touching the above formula,
\[ c = d, \]
and another short line,
\[ e = f \]
followed by a longer line that we want to go beyond the limit so it wraps.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your take, but I'm afraid it doesn't really bring me further than what I wrote in the last paragraph of my question. My main problem is that there's still too much space below `c=d` in each of your sample outputs. By the way, by default, (La)TeX does _not_ set `\belowdisplayshortskip=\abovedisplayshortskip` - that would be horrible!

Comment: @HendrikVogt To tell you the truth, I don't see the problem. If "really" the two lines conflict, then use a strut in the line below the display to move it down. If the superscripts are not at the center of the line there wouldn't be any conflict.

Comment: There's no _conflict_, but there's _too much_ space. _After_ "and another short line", a short skip is used, and that's good. What I don't like is the large skip _before_ "and another short line". This is what my question is about, a "real" `\belowdisplayshortskip`, i.e., the line _below_ `c=d` is short, so the skip should be _short_. Clearer now?

Comment: using a `gather*` environment and `\shortintertext` from `mathtools` is a way out. But an automatized way would be much better.