# When should we use a blank line?

Tags: spacing, best-practices

I only know that we have to make at least one blank line between two adjacent paragraphs.

My question is:

***What is the proper way to make use of a blank line ?***

For example:

1. Is it recommended to make a blank line between heading command call, e.g. `\chapter{}`, and the first text content as follows?

   ```
   \chapter{Introduction}

   In this chapter we ....
   ```

   or

   ```
   ... that is proven true.

   \chapter{Limit}
   ```
2. Is it recommended to make a blank line between two consecutive display equations as follows?

   ```
   \[ \sin x \] 

   \[ \cos x \]
   ```
3. Is it recommended to make a blank line between a sentence and a display equation as follows?

   ```
   Assume we have

   \[
     \cos x
   \]
   ```

   or

   ```
   \[
     \cos x
   \]

   that satisfies ...
   ```
4. etc...

---

### Edit 1:

1. How about `\bigskip`, `\vspace{}`? Does each of them needs one blank line before and one blank line after as follows:

   ```
   Yes. This is a book.

   \bigskip

   Commander, please open the silo!
   ```

   or

   ```
   Yes. This is a book.

   \vspace{1km}

   Commander, please open the silo!
   ```

Comment: @Joseph, a pair of back-tiks cannot span multiple lines I think.

Comment: See also the explanation in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565/how-can-i-get-rid-of-indentation-after-an-equation/566#566

Comment: Oops, I accidentally left the following comment on Hendrik's answer instead of the question. Hendrik has the right answer, I think. I'd only point out (and this doesn't deserve its own answer) that a blank line after \chapter doesn't matter. It will display the same. In the other cases, starting a new paragraph (by using a blank line) will have an effect.

Comment: @xport: for source code in lists, you need to indent the code by an *additional* four spaces. I’ve changed the text for you. If you don’t like how this renders, you can roll the change back. One thing that is still wrong about this posting is that two empty lines are inserted in the code, in place of just one. This appears to be a bug, and I’m reporting it on meta.

Comment: @Konrad, thanks for editing. It looks much better than my setting before.

Comment: @Konrad, **Back-tick back-slash opening-square-brace back-tick DOES NOT WORK: `\[`**

Comment: @xport: only in comments (markup in comments is amputated, don’t rely on it too much). In the actual question/answer text, the same code works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can tell you what I'd do in these 3 cases:

1.: After `\chapter{}` and similar command I'd *always* use a blank line as it makes the document structure clearer. Moreover, "In this chapter ..." is the start of a paragraph.

2.: I wouldn't use a blank line here if both displays belong to the same paragraph. However, I usually wouldn't use two consecutive displays at all; I'd use `align*` or `gather*` instead.

3.: In that particular case don't use blank lines as everything is within one paragraph. Speaking of clarity of the document structure, I'd say that

```
Assume we have    
\[
  \cos x
\]
that satisfies ...
```

is clear enough. Only use a blank line after the display if the paragraph ends after the display.

4.: As for your extra question about vertical spacing commands: In the context you provide, I'd always surround them with blank lines for clarity of the document structure. I sometimes use them before a display like this; then you mustn't put a blank line:

```
... some text
\vspace{-1ex}
\[
  ...
\]
```

I should point out that manual corrections like in this last example are rarely needed, and you should only use them if you're sure that you know what you're doing.

Comment: In 3 also the blank lines produces bad spacing.

Comment: @Hendrik, thanks for almost complete answer. One more case has been added above regarding `\bigskip` and `vspace`.

Comment: @Hendrik: no4 looks wrong for correct typesetting with TeX. because the lengths `abovedisplayskip` and `abovedisplayshortskip` should only be used here.

Comment: @Herbert: I tried to word it carefully: Note the "sometimes". I [do know about the displayskips](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3404/1235), but sometimes they don't work out nicely for me, so I put manual corrections. The situation in no.4 happens, e.g., if there's a lonely integral sign in my display and the overlap is just too small for the shortskip. I know that I must only do stuff like that in the very end.

Comment: @Hendrik: please give an example

Comment: @Herbert: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean I should add a more explicit example to my answer, or can't you imagine why I would want to use this kind of `\vspace{-1ex}` at all?

Comment: @Hendrik: I am interested in mathematical typesetting and want to know where a `vspace{-1ex}` should make sense when using `\[ ... \]`. From my point of view it is wrong. But I cannot say more without a complete example.

Comment: @Hendrik: here an example were it is totally wrong: `\documentclass{article}`
`\begin{document}`
... some text
`\vspace{-1ex}`
`\[ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x \]`
bar
`\end{document}`

Comment: @Herbert: Please be patient with me; I won't really have time before tomorrow. In your above example, it could be that I'd do something like that if there is some additional expression before the integral sign.

Comment: @Herbert: OK, here's a snippet of [something I really wrote](http://i.imgur.com/CLbxI.png). I did use `\vspace{-1ex}` before the `\[` to achieve the spacing. (And I think the reduced spacing before the display looks better.) If you have a better suggestion, I'm very interested.

Comment: @Hendrik: looks like a complete wrong spacing. Can you send me the code snippet to `hvoss@tug.org`, please. And with the used documentclass

Comment: @Herbert: It's part of a really long text, so before I send you anything, can you please tell me what's wrong about it?

Comment: @Hendrik: the line over the formula ends before it starts, the reason why TeX should use `\abovedisplayshortskip` to insert less vertical space. It seems that in this case `\abovedisplayshortskip` has the same value as `\abovedisplayskip` which is wrong.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks a lot for your comment. I'm sorry, I did indeed mess around with the shortskips, for reasons you can find [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/3404/edit). Here's a minimal example without messing around: `\documentclass{article} \textheight=2cm \begin{document} \def\blah{blah blah blah blah } \blah\blah\blah\blah\blah\blah\blah and we infer that \vspace{-1ex} \[ T(\xi_\theta)f(\theta) \le \bigl(T(\xi_0)f(0)\bigr)^{1-\theta} \bigl(T(\xi_1)f(1)\bigr)^\theta. \] Blah \blah\blah$\|f(j)\|_{p_j}\le1$ \blah \end{document}`

Comment: @Hendrik: without the `\vskip` you get the correct typesetting for displayed math equations when the line above ends before the math expressions begins. It is a vertical space which is 10pt smaller than for a longer line. However, if you do not like this, you can alternatively define `\abovedisplayshortskip=-1ex plus 3pt`

Comment: @Herbert: As I said, I do know about the displayskips. And I did already mess around a bit with them to adjust them to what I like. However, they make some automatic rough decision what skip should look good, and sometimes I'm not happy with the automatic decision. I still don't quite see what I can do except manual corrections at that specific places. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks for your above comments. They made me add a word of caution to my answer. If you think that the answer is OK with this addition, and if it was you who cast the downvote, then please consider reverting it. (If you think it's still not OK, then I'd be glad to know an alternative. The only point that I'm quite sure about is that sometimes I do need manual corrections.)

Comment: @Hendrik: the downvote was already by mistake, didn't know what the "golden" pen should be ...

Comment: @Herbert: Oh, I see, you haven't really voted so far. The faq tells you that your votes are most welcome!

Answer (score 5):

it gives wrong vertical spacing, when you use blank lines before, between and after display math environments. Compare the following output, where the equation environment has not the same spacing over and under the math expression.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
The line above the equation.

\[ f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(i-\frac{1}{2i}\right) \]

The line below the equation.
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
The line above the equation.

\begin{equation} 
f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(i-\frac{1}{2i}\right) 
\end{equation}

The line below the equation.
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
The line above the equation.
%
\[ f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(i-\frac{1}{2i}\right) \]
%
The line below the equation.
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
The line above the equation.
%
\begin{equation} 
f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(i-\frac{1}{2i}\right) 
\end{equation}
%
The line below the equation.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. From this I know that blanks lines before and/or after display equation (either `\ [...\ ]` or `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`) will produce different spacing on the output.

Answer (score 2):

For your new part 4, the answer is it doesn't matter. `\bigskip` expands to `\vspace\bigskipamount` and `\vspace` contains code that deals with it be used in horizontal mode (namely, it inserts the `\vskip` into the surrounding vertical list after the current line using `\vadjust`).