# Syntax of Using Math Mode: Empty Lines (Beginner Question)

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations, line-breaking, syntax

I'm just starting to learn LaTeX. I tried typing

```
\begin{equation*}

(math goes here)

\end{equation*}
```

and I got a whole bunch of errors. It seems LaTeX interpreted the empty line as the equation: when it saw nothing there, I guess it just ended math mode? It then said my other commands needed `$`'s so I assume that's what happened. When I typed

```
\begin{equation*}
(math goes here)
\end{equation*}
```

everything was fine. So I'm confused. If LaTeX sees an empty line in an environment, does it just interpret this as me changing my mind, and deciding not to use the declared environment?

Comment: Blank lines are disallowed in math mode.

Comment: a blank line is understood by tex as indicating a paragraph break.  and math mode isn't allowed to continue across multiple paragraphs.  hence a blank line within a math environment is reported as an error.

Comment: Related: [When should we use a blank line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7831/5764)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Blank lines in `align` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10355/5764)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An empty line in TeX should never be used just to arrange the source. It is an *instruction* exactly the same as the command `\par` which ends a paragraph and
starts TeX's line breaking algorithm to split a paragraph into lines.

So it is not allowed in display math and it should never be used on the line before
display math either, in that position it does not generate an error but forces
TeX to take recovery action that produces a spurious white paragraph on the line above the display.