# Math environments: Allow empty lines?

Tags: amsmath

Compiling the following document will raise the errors

```
Paragraph ended before \align was complete
```

and

```
Displaymath should end with $$
```

because par-breaks are not allowed in math environments/displaymath.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
Empty 

are not allowed.
\end{align}
$$
Empty lines

are not allowed
$$
\end{document}
```

While editing however, I frequently accidentially compile after hitting enter (creating a new line) and before adding any content, hence I am searching for a method to allow paragraph breaks in math mode, ideally ignoring them.

Just for comparison, if I needed only display-math without AMS environments, a viable solution would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\everydisplay{\def\par{\mathbf{\color{red}-forgotten-par-}}}
$$ 
Empty\,lines

are\,now\,allowed

but\,you\,get\,a\,reminder
$$
\end{document}
```

Is there some solution that works across all common math environments?

Comment: If a well understand you want to enforce line breaks (newline) inside  math mode ?

Comment: Don't use `$$` in LaTeX to begin with. See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230338/syntax-of-using-math-mode-empty-lines-beginner-question

Comment: @SAM No, I really only want to avoid compilation failure when I start a new (source code) line in math mode and haven't typed anything yet.

Comment: @egrep I mostly used `$$` only to demonstrate, that the "problem" occurs across multiple macros. Thanks for the link though; Using almost exclusively AMS environments, I never heard of that.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend it, but if luatex is an option, it allows both these errors to be disabled without making any changes to the macros.

```
\suppressmathparerror = 1
\suppresslongerror = 1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
Empty 

are not allowed.
\end{align}
$$
Empty lines

are not allowed
$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer for first version of the question.

You are seeking problems. Partial solution, working for $$, but not `amsmath`-based environments is below. Check it, please and **never use it**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\let\normalpar=\par
\def\par{\ifmmode \else\normalpar \fi}
\begin{align}
Empty 
%
are not allowed.
\end{align}
$$
Empty lines

are not allowed
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this worse than using `\everydisplay`?

Comment: @kdb It is an answer for the first version, when OP wrote nothing about `\everydisplay`. And the main thesis is `never use it`. The right way is changing customaries.