# Math mode code indentation

Tags: math-mode, sourcecode

How is math mode processed in TeX? Is typing `\n` (in editor) in math mode equivalent to one space? I am asking, because I struggled to find a bug in source code (between a lot of matrices :-) ), and the reason was following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}                      
\begin{document}       
$1    
2$                      
\end{document}
```

compiles,

```latex
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}       
$1                      

2$    
\end{document}
```

but this does not. (`missing $` error)

I know that I can add `%` between to maintain source code style, but the question is about why above error happens.

Comment: Related: [Syntax of Using Math Mode: Empty Lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230338/134144) To summarize: empty lines are not allowed in math mode as they are interpreted as a paragraph break that is not possible in math mode.

Comment: Thanks! somehow I couldn't find questions about this