# Align equation in a proof

Tags: align, alignment

I am about to cry

This worked perfectly before and the equations just won't align correctly. I want them to align under the 2nd equal sign..
Constantly get different errors, 'missing $ inserted' or missing { which doesn't make any sense

````
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{align}

 L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \chi(n)n^{-s} &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S(n)(n^{-s} - (n-1)^{-s}) \\
     &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S(n)\int_{n}^{n+1} x^{-s-1}dx \\
     &=s\int_{1}^{\infty}S(x)x^{-s-1}dx
\end{align}```

\end{proof}
````

Comment: Don't use empty lines inside of `align`. Simply remove it or comment it out.

Comment: See also: [Syntax of Using Math Mode: Empty Lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230338/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have any blank spaces within the 'align' environment.

Beyond that, I think it should work fine. I can't see any other errors in the code.