# LaTex math mode coding

Tags: logic

This is my code, in `\begin{align*}` why am I getting an error saying I'm missing a `$`?

```
\begin{document}
%%
\begin{proof*}
\begin{align*}

1.\; & (p \land q \rightarrow r, u \rightarrow \lnot r, u \land q) &&\aside{Premise}\\
2.\; & p \land q \rightarrow r   &&\aside{Premise} \\
3.\; & \equiv u \rightarrow \lnot r     &&\aside{Premise} \\
4.\; & \equiv u \land q                 &&\aside{Premise} \\
5.\; & \equiv u                         &&\aside{Specialization:3} \\
6.\; & \equiv \land r                   &&\aside{Modus Pones:2,4} \\
7.\; & \equiv \lnot (p \land q)         &&\aside{Modus Tollens:1,5} \\
8.\; & \equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q      &&\aside{De Morgan's: ^} \\
9.\; & \equiv q                         &&\aside{Specialization:3}\\
10.\; & \equiv \lnot \lnot q             &&\aside{Double Negation:8}\\
11.\; & \equiv \lnot p                   &&\aside{Elimination:7,9}\\
                    
\end{align*}
\end{proof*}        

%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document begining with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  What is `\aside`

Comment: aside apparently just adds a comment, im doing it for a logic proof. what is code fragment?

Comment: Please, rather extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your error. If I put your `align*` into standard document container and define `\aside` command, I don't get any error ...

Comment: Remove the blank lines.

Comment: thank you so much!!! how do i start a standard document container and how do i define aside?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

To long for a comment ...

Since you not provide MWE, the following is based on usual use of the `proof` environment (see [Theorems](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems)). In it is considered @Mico comment (removed are blank lines in `align` environment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newcommand\aside[1]{\text{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof} % <---
\begin{align*}
    1.\quad & (p \land q \to r, u \to \lnot r, u \land q) 
                        &&\aside{Premise}\\
    2.\quad & p \land q \rightarrow r   &&\aside{Premise} \\
    3.\quad & \equiv u \rightarrow \lnot r     &&\aside{Premise} \\
    4.\quad & \equiv u \land q                 &&\aside{Premise} \\
    5.\quad & \equiv u                         &&\aside{Specialization:3} \\
    6.\quad & \equiv \land r                   &&\aside{Modus Pones:2,4} \\
    7.\quad & \equiv \lnot (p \land q)         &&\aside{Modus Tollens:1,5} \\
    8.\quad & \equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q      &&\aside{De Morgan's: } \\
    9.\quad & \equiv q                         &&\aside{Specialization:3}\\
    10.\quad & \equiv \lnot \lnot q            &&\aside{Double Negation:8}\\
    11.\quad & \equiv \lnot p                  &&\aside{Elimination:7,9}
        \qedhere
\end{align*}%
    \end{proof} % <---
\end{document}
```

[image]

It gives no errors! Where and how you define ˙proof*`?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `align` environment cannot process empty lines. So remove the empty lines and it should compile fine

Comment: The reason is simple: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230339/82917.