# Space between equations/figure depends on previous paragraph/newline

Tags: spacing, graphics, equations, paragraphs, text

I need to rewrite a Latex book and optimze the code and found a "problem" which I cant solve and dont find a global solution.

In my opinion the code is better to read, if there is a newline/paragraph between text and equation-block.
But this leads to an bigger cap between text and equation, which I try to avoid.

My question is, is it possible to insert a new line in code (for easier code reading) without increasing the gap between text and equation?

Here is my minimal code example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Gap}
\section{testcase 1}
This is a test sentence and has nothing to do with the real problem.
    \begin{equation}
        a=b+x
    \end{equation}
This is a test sentence and has nothing to do with the real problem.


\section{testcase 2}
This is a test sentence and has nothing to do with the real problem.

    \begin{equation}
        a=b+x
    \end{equation}

This is a test sentense and has nothing to do with the real problem.

\end{document}
```

Here a picture how it looks like:
[image: Text]

I know its not a big difference but still.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Empty lines generate new paragraphs. _Never_ put display math between empty lines. If you do it for better code readability then use `%` as ivankokan said.

Comment: You can leave a blank after the equation if you intend to indicate that the following text is a new paragraph but never leave a blank line before the equation.

Comment: The answer to this question explains the reason why a display block should not be preceded by a blank line: [Syntax of Using Math Mode: Empty Lines (Beginner Question)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230338)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a semantic difference as well.

Compare where the second sentence starts (paragraph indent). In one case you have started a new paragraph (with the empty line), in the other (without the empty line) you have just continued the current paragraph.

If you want to have an "empty line" in the source code without an impact on the typesetting, use `%` at its beginning to comment it.

Comment: Ok thank you for this explanation and tipp.