# Display math deadly sin in l2tabu

Tags: math-mode

As a follow-up to [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to), what *really* is wrong with the vertical spacing as stated in `l2tabu` introduced by using `$$...$$` instead of `\[...\]`?

As there does not seem to be an elaboration of this in `l2tabu` except for the remark that vertical spacing is modified and rendered inconsistent, illustrative examples comparing the different outputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the bigger problem with `$$...$$` is that it won't work with anything that modifies displayed math (e.g. the `[fleqn]` option) how important is it to worry about the vertical spacing issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to). Arg. I didn't see that you already cited this question. I am sleepy.

Comment: I think this is a fine question and you got a good answer to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should avoid empty lines before and after displayed equations. Compare:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Equation using \LaTeX\ notation
%
\[ y = x^{2} \]
%
Equation using \TeX\ notation
%
$$ y = x^{2} $$
%
end of the part without empty lines\newpage

Equation using \LaTeX\ notation

\[ y = x^{2} \]

Equation using \TeX\ notation

$$ y = x^{2} $$

end of the part with empty lines
\end{document}
```

[image: ...]

Comment: in this case there is no difference. But as already mentioned in some other cases there will be a difference.

Comment: "You should avoid empty lines before and after displayed equations." Is this advice intended strictly, or is it acceptable to skip a line after a displayed equation if you actually want to start a new paragraph?

Answer (score 16):

The only difference as far as spacing is concerned is that `\[...\]` will use `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` instead of `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip` that would be used by `$$...$$` in case the math display is started in vertical mode. The code

```
\setbox0=\vbox{\hrule height 0pt % to avoid gobbling vskips
\[a=b\]
A word.}
\showthe\ht0

\setbox0=\vbox{\hrule height 0pt % to avoid gobbling vskips
$$a=b$$
A word.}
\showthe\ht0
\showthe\abovedisplayskip
\showthe\belowdisplayskip
\showthe\abovedisplayshortskip
\showthe\belowdisplayshortskip
```

will give the following information:

```
?
> 44.0pt.
l.27 \showthe\ht0

? 
> 30.0pt.
l.32 \showthe\ht0

? 
> 10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt.
l.33 \showthe\abovedisplayskip

? 
> 10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt.
l.34 \showthe\belowdisplayskip

? 
> 0.0pt plus 3.0pt.
l.35 \showthe\abovedisplayshortskip

? 
> 6.0pt plus 3.0pt minus 3.0pt.
l.36 \showthe\belowdisplayshortskip
```

The 14pt difference is exactly the result of (10+10)-(0+6). Actually the `\hrule height 0pt` here does almost nothing because of `\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt`.

This doesn't happen when **amsmath** is loaded (the "short" skips are used in this case).

The definition of `\[` in the LaTeX kernel is

```
\def\[{%
\relax\ifmmode
  \@badmath
\else
  \ifvmode
    \nointerlineskip\makebox[.6\linewidth]{}
  \fi
  $$
\fi}
```

that explains why the "non short" skips are used at the beginning of a paragraph: the LaTeX kernel starts a paragraph with an empty line long enough to prevent the use of the "short" skips. I believe that this has been added by Lamport to cope with authors that leave an empty line before `\[`.

Comment: Seems like a better choice for Lamport would have been to just make `\abovedisplayshortskip` equal to `\abovedisplayskip`.

Comment: @TH I'd say no: when the document is properly written, the settings are good. Setting the "short" skip equal to the "normal" one would be wrong, causing a big hole when the line preceding the paragraph is short.

Comment: @TH: I'd also say no, for the same reasons. @egreg: Does your answer mean that the accepted answer to the question behind the link in the OP is wrong? (By the way, I do agree with your comment, but I think [the implementation of `\belowdisplayshortskip` is rather strange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3404/is-it-possible-to-have-a-real-belowdisplayshortskip).)

Comment: @Hendrik, egreg: I think you both misunderstood. I'm not saying that Lamport's decision to effectively ignore the `\abovedisplayshortskip` was a good one. I was just saying that an easier way to have them behave the same was to set them equal, not make sure that the short version would ever be used.

Comment: @Hendrik: it's not wrong, but incomplete. The *real* reason why `$$` should not be used is that it hinders LaTeX (and amsmath) in doing what they should do to displays.

Comment: @Jasper: with amsmath the two vboxes would give the same result; but using `$$` with amsmath can break many other things.

Comment: @TH: I have now read your last comment a few times, but I still don't get it. Maybe it contains some typos? Or my brain is permanently bungled?

Comment: @Hendrik: Yeah, typo. The last sentence should be, "I was just saying that an easier way to have them [them being display math when the previous line was short and when it was long] behave the same was to set them [them being `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip`] equal, not make sure the short version would _not_ ever be used.